# Windows 8 store app HTML-Javascript Developing Music Player Application to play local music files

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I am developing a Music Player application which plays local mp3 files from music player.
In my app there is an option to add mp3 files from music folder to the Playlist.
The problem I am facing is when I set local path of the mp3 file as source to Html 5 audio tag it throws an error.
Below is the code

```
audioPlayer.src = "C:\Users\Sharma\Music\JiveHD Songs";
```

I am using sqlite database to maintain playlist.
Can anyone help me on this.
So that I can play local mp3 files in my html5-javascript windows store app.

Comment: It's Unspecified error.onerror event is raised.

Answer (score 1):

Have you selected the Music Library capability in your package.appxmanifest?  You will need to select that for programmatic access to the user's music library.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx for more details.

Double-click the Package.appxmanifest file in Visual Studio, click the Capabilities tab, and make sure "Music Library" is checked.

Comment: Music library permission is checked.